# How to remove multiple headers from dataframe and keeps just the first python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a csv file that presents multiple headers, all are repeated like in this example:

```
1                     2     3   4
0            POSITION_T  PROB  ID  
1                 2.385   2.0   1  
2            POSITION_T  PROB  ID 
3                 3.074   6.0   3  
4                 6.731   8.0   4    
6            POSITION_T  PROB  ID  
7                12.508   2.0   1  
8                12.932   4.0   2  
9                12.985   4.0   2
```

I want to remove the duplicated headers to get the a final document like this:

```
0            POSITION_T  PROB  ID  
1                 2.385   2.0   1   
3                 3.074   6.0   3  
4                 6.731   8.0   4     
7                12.508   2.0   1  
8                12.932   4.0   2  
9                12.985   4.0   2
```

The way in which I trying to remove these headers is by using:

```
df1 = [df!='POSITION_T'][df!='PROB'][df!='ID']
```

But that produce the error `TypeError: Could not compare ['TRACK_ID'] with block values`
Some ideas? thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the actual text file look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filtering out by field value:

```
df = pd.read_table('yourfile.csv', header=None, delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=1)
df.columns = ['0','POSITION_T','PROB','ID']
del df['0']

# filtering out the rows with `POSITION_T` value in corresponding column
df = df[df.POSITION_T.str.contains('POSITION_T') == False]

print(df)
```

The output:

```
  POSITION_T PROB ID
1      2.385  2.0  1
3      3.074  6.0  3
4      6.731  8.0  4
6     12.508  2.0  1
7     12.932  4.0  2
8     12.985  4.0  2
```

Comment: I have a similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/q/68705981/16421119

Comment: Would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

To keep the bottom level column names only:

```
df.columns=[multicols[-1] for multicols in df.columns]
```

Comment: This worked for me (though in my use case, I was taking only the top level)

Answer (score 1):

This is not ideal!  The best way to deal with this would be to handle it in the file parsing.

```
mask = df.iloc[:, 0] == 'POSITION_T'
d1 = df[~mask]
d1.columns = df.loc[mask.idxmax].values

d1 = d1.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
d1

   POSITION_T  PROB  ID
1                      
1       2.385   2.0   1
3       3.074   6.0   3
4       6.731   8.0   4
7      12.508   2.0   1
8      12.932   4.0   2
9      12.985   4.0   2
```

Comment: Hi @pirsquared, I have a similar issue here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68705981/16421119 Would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
past_data=pd.read_csv("book.csv")

past_data = past_data[past_data.LAT.astype(str).str.contains('LAT') == False]

print(past_data)
```

1. Replace the CSV (here: book.csv)
2. Replace your variable names (here: past_data)
3. Replace all the LAT with your any of your column name
4. That's All/ your multiple headers will be removed