# pandas not writing all the rows to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am reading multiple csv's using pandas while writing the final csv it only shows data of the last file that was read in a dataframe. If you see final.csv
you will only find the last 4 lines.

Problem:

Read
:

Anarget;02/09/2019 14:39:00;02/09/2019 14:42:00;Europe/Dublin;0
0  Anarget;02/09/2019 14:39:00;02/09/2019 14:42:0...
1  Anarget;02/09/2019 14:42:00;02/09/2019 14:45:0...
2  Anarget;02/09/2019 14:45:00;02/09/2019 14:48:0...
3  Anarget;02/09/2019 14:48:00;02/09/2019 14:51:0...
  Anarget;02/09/2019 14:51:00;02/09/2019 14:54:00;Europe/Dublin;0
0  Anarget;02/09/2019 14:51:00;02/09/2019 14:54:0...
1  Anarget;02/09/2019 14:54:00;02/09/2019 14:57:0...
2  Anarget;02/09/2019 14:57:00;02/09/2019 15:00:0...
  Anarget;02/09/2019 15:00:00;02/09/2019 15:03:00;Europe/Dublin;0
0  Anarget;02/09/2019 15:00:00;02/09/2019 15:03:0...
1  Anarget;02/09/2019 15:03:00;02/09/2019 15:06:0...
2  Anarget;02/09/2019 15:06:00;02/09/2019 15:09:0...

Write: Final.csv

Anarget;02/09/2019 15:00:00;02/09/2019 15:03:00;Europe/Dublin;0
Anarget;02/09/2019 15:00:00;02/09/2019 15:03:00;Europe/Dublin;0
Anarget;02/09/2019 15:03:00;02/09/2019 15:06:00;Europe/Dublin;0
Anarget;02/09/2019 15:06:00;02/09/2019 15:09:00;Europe/Dublin;0

Solution:

All the data in the above format:

```py
def get_csv_files(client, bucket):
    csv_files = []
    content = client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket).get('Contents')
    for obj in content:
        key = obj.get('Key')
        if '.csv' in key:
            csv_files.append(key)

    return csv_files


for key in get_csv_files(s3_client, bucket):
    file_body = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key).get('Body')

    df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(file_body.read()))
    df.columns = [c.replace(' ', '_') for c in df.columns]

    mask = df.iloc[:, 0] == 'Asset_Id'
    d1 = df[~mask]
    d1.columns = df.loc[mask.idxmax].values

    print(d1)
    d1.to_csv(r'final.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove multiple headers from dataframe and keeps just the first python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004141/how-to-remove-multiple-headers-from-dataframe-and-keeps-just-the-first-python)

Comment: Did not work! it gave me an error which I am not able to resolve ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 6 elements