# Trying to parse through an xml file and put the text data into a dictionary using Python. keyerror: 0

Tags: python, xml, csv, parsing, elementtree

I am parsing through an XML file(below) using the Python elementTree package.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Cp1252"?>
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <COLUMN NAME='TITLE'>Empire Burlesque</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME='ARTIST'>Bob Dylan</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME='COUNTRY'>USA</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME='COMPANY'>Columbia</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME='PRICE'>10.90</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME='YEAR'>1985</COLUMN>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <COLUMN NAME='TITLE'>Hide your heart</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME='ARTIST'>Bonnie Tyler</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME='COUNTRY'>UK</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME='COMPANY'>CBS Records</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME='PRICE'>9.90</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME='YEAR'>1988</COLUMN>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <COLUMN NAME='TITLE'>Greatest Hits</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME='ARTIST'>Dolly Parton</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME='COUNTRY'>USA</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME='COMPANY'>RCA</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME='PRICE'>9.90</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME='YEAR'>1982</COLUMN>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Now, I want to put the entire text of each respective attribute i.e. TITLE, ARTIST, etc. into a dictionary file and then write the text into a csv file into each row. Below is my python program.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring
import csv

tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

orgdata = {}
orglist = []

csv_columns = ['TITLE','ARTIST','COUNTRY','COMPANY','PRICE','YEAR']

count = 0
for child in root:
    for sub in child:
        if sub.attrib.get('NAME') == 'TITLE':
            orgdata['TITLE'] = sub.text
        if sub.attrib.get('NAME') == 'ARTIST':
            orgdata['ARTIST'] = sub.text
        if sub.attrib.get('NAME') == 'COUNTRY':
            orgdata['COUNTRY'] = sub.text
        if sub.attrib.get('NAME') == 'COMPANY':
            orgdata['COMPANY'] = sub.text
        if sub.attrib.get('NAME') == 'PRICE':
            orgdata['PRICE'] = sub.text
        if sub.attrib.get('NAME') == 'YEAR':
            orgdata['YEAR'] = sub.text
        tocsv = orgdata
orglist.append(orgdata)
k = tocsv[0].keys()
with open('orgfile.txt','w+') as csvfile:
    dic = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,k,delimiter='|',extrasaction='ignore')
    dic.writeheader()
    dic.writerows(tocsv)
```

This code results in the key error:0

```
$ python sample.py                                                                                                                                                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 30, in <module>
    k = tocsv[0].keys()
KeyError: 0
```

Is there a way to fix this and get the data into the CSV file without the duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think you meant `orglist[0].keys()` instead of `tocsv[0].keys()`. This will solve your error.

According to your second question which is:

> Is there a way to fix this and get the data into the CSV file without the duplicates?

The answer to that is yes and you can do that in just three lines of code using `pandas.DataFrame` like so:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(orglist)
>>> df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
>>> print(df)
```

### Edit

So, your code should look like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring
import pandas as pd


tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

orglist = []
for child in root:
    orgdata = {}
    for sub in child:
        if sub.attrib.get('NAME') == 'TITLE':
            orgdata['TITLE'] = sub.text
        if sub.attrib.get('NAME') == 'ARTIST':
            orgdata['ARTIST'] = sub.text
        if sub.attrib.get('NAME') == 'COUNTRY':
            orgdata['COUNTRY'] = sub.text
        if sub.attrib.get('NAME') == 'COMPANY':
            orgdata['COMPANY'] = sub.text
        if sub.attrib.get('NAME') == 'PRICE':
            orgdata['PRICE'] = sub.text
        if sub.attrib.get('NAME') == 'YEAR':
            orgdata['YEAR'] = sub.text
        tocsv = orgdata
    orglist.append(orgdata)

df = pd.DataFrame(orglist)
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Which would print:

```
         ARTIST      COMPANY COUNTRY  PRICE             TITLE  YEAR
0     Bob Dylan     Columbia     USA  10.90  Empire Burlesque  1985
1  Bonnie Tyler  CBS Records      UK   9.90   Hide your heart  1988
2  Dolly Parton          RCA     USA   9.90     Greatest Hits  1982
```

Comment: Thank you, the solution worked well. For the duplicates, I tried using the pandas which worked good(better than my other solutions) but it's printing out the headers each time along with the values. I tried another solution : '[link] 
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004141/how-to-remove-multiple-headers-from-dataframe-and-keeps-just-the-first-python)' but still didn't work. Any suggestions.

Comment: I edited my answer... hope this answers your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simplify this a bit using `findall`:

```
In [20]: x = """
    ...: <CATALOG>
    ...:   <CD>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='TITLE'>Empire Burlesque</COLUMN>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='ARTIST'>Bob Dylan</COLUMN>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='COUNTRY'>USA</COLUMN>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='COMPANY'>Columbia</COLUMN>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='PRICE'>10.90</COLUMN>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='YEAR'>1985</COLUMN>
    ...:   </CD>
    ...:   <CD>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='TITLE'>Hide your heart</COLUMN>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='ARTIST'>Bonnie Tyler</COLUMN>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='COUNTRY'>UK</COLUMN>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='COMPANY'>CBS Records</COLUMN>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='PRICE'>9.90</COLUMN>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='YEAR'>1988</COLUMN>
    ...:   </CD>
    ...:   <CD>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='TITLE'>Greatest Hits</COLUMN>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='ARTIST'>Dolly Parton</COLUMN>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='COUNTRY'>USA</COLUMN>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='COMPANY'>RCA</COLUMN>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='PRICE'>9.90</COLUMN>
    ...:     <COLUMN NAME='YEAR'>1982</COLUMN>
    ...:   </CD>
    ...: </CATALOG>"""

In [21]:

In [21]: xdata = fromstring(x)

In [22]: results = []

In [23]: for cd in xdata.findall('.//CD'):
    ...:     each_result = {}
    ...:     for each in cd.findall('.//COLUMN'):
    ...:         each_result[each.attrib.get('NAME')] = each.text
    ...:     results.append(each_result)
```

which results in:

```
In [24]: results
Out[24]:
[{'TITLE': 'Empire Burlesque',
  'ARTIST': 'Bob Dylan',
  'COUNTRY': 'USA',
  'COMPANY': 'Columbia',
  'PRICE': '10.90',
  'YEAR': '1985'},
 {'TITLE': 'Hide your heart',
  'ARTIST': 'Bonnie Tyler',
  'COUNTRY': 'UK',
  'COMPANY': 'CBS Records',
  'PRICE': '9.90',
  'YEAR': '1988'},
 {'TITLE': 'Greatest Hits',
  'ARTIST': 'Dolly Parton',
  'COUNTRY': 'USA',
  'COMPANY': 'RCA',
  'PRICE': '9.90',
  'YEAR': '1982'}]
```

Comment: This solution works. I'm able to delete the duplicates. But, I should not be using findall. Can I do it using find or some other function? Thank you.